# Inaccurate output of OSRM match service

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geo, osrm

How can I improve the output of match call?

On a fairly simple input segment, I get a complex one. Red track is input one, Green track is osrm's route.
[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CpD2.jpg)

#input coordinates=244, #output coordinates=846
Order of input gps coords is ok.

I've tried many sets of input parameters. Drfault set is steps=False, overview=full, geometry=polyline, timestamps=None, radius=None, annotations=False, gaps=ignore, tidy=True, waypoints=None

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]